# How Can I to remove the second enumeration in the sections?

Tags: macros, sectioning, packages, sections-paragraphs, section-titles

I wish to remove the second enumeration of sections in my text, i.e, where has section 1.1 I want section 1. How can I do it?

Comment: section headings are defined by the documentclass, about which you have given no information, also 1.1 is section 1 in chapter 1, when you get to chapter 2 do you want the counter to rrestart and just say 1 or carry on with the first section of chapter 2 being section 7 (or whatever number)

Comment: I'm using the class 'book'

Comment: and what what number do you want the first section of chapter 2 to have? Normally the number resets to 1 so three sections in chapter 1 are 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 then 2.1, do you want 1,2,3,1 or 1,2,3,4

Comment: @CíceroHitzschky: Try with `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}` in your preamble. Are you also using [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)?

Comment: Thank you!!! I got it! The \renewcommand above worked!! Yes! I'm using the hyperref. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose chapters 1 and 2 have 2 sections each and that the `book` class is in use.

- By default, the four sections are labeled `1.1`, `1.2`, `2.1`, and `2.2`.
- If you want them labeled `1`, `2`, `1`, and `2`, i.e., with a reset each time LaTeX executes a `\chapter` directive, you should run

  ```
  \renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
  ```

  in the preamble.

  Note that this numbering/labeling style can easily create confusion if you cross-reference sections: Is section "2" being cross-referenced the one in the current chapter, or is it maybe in some other chapter? If it's the latter, which chapter? If your document contains such cross-references, you may want to prefix the applicable chapter number in order to eliminate this source of confusion. To do so, you should run the following code in the preamble:

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\p@section}{\thechapter.} % prefix macro
  \makeatother
  ```
- If you want the sections labeled `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`, i.e., numbered consecutively throughut the document, you should run

  ```
  \counterwithout{section}{chapter}
  ```

  in the preamble.